# Does a function exist that creates more or less this kind of graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

I need to plot this graph into a 2D grid, but I'm having a hard time finding a way to do this efficiently and in a way where I can change a few variables to make the appearance slightly different.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aDuW.png)

Does someone know of a function that could potentially create something like the above?

Comment: You will definitely not get this by plotting $y=f(x)$ for any function $f,$ because the graph fails the vertical line test.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like
$$
\begin{equation}
x(t) = t + \sin(2t) \\
y(t) = \cos(t)
\end{equation}
$$